# Converting edittext input to an integer

Tags: java, android, math

trying to evaluate a correct answer to a simple maths question. Is this the correct way of going about grabbing the input and coverting it into an int to be comared with another int?

```
    public void checkAnswer(){
       int mm;
        //answer = editText.getText().toString();
        mm = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());

        if (mm == correctAnswer){

        score++;
        scoredisplay.setText("" + score);

    }
```

here is how i set correctAnswer

```
public void getQuestion(){

    random1 = (int)(Math.random()*100);
    random2 = (int)(Math.random()*10);

    int i1 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));

    if(i1 == 1){
    question = (random1 + "+" + random2);
    correctAnswer = random1 + random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);
    }
    if(i1 == 2){
    question = (random1 + "-" +random2);
    correctAnswer = random1 - random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);

    }
    if(i1 == 3){
    question = random1 + "/" +random2;
    correctAnswer = random1 / random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);

    }
    if(i1 == 4){
    question = (random1 + "*" +random2);
    correctAnswer = random1 * random2;
    editTextEquation.setText(question);


    }


    else{

        score--;
        scoredisplay.setText("" + score);
    }
```

button

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v){
switch(v.getId()){
case R.id.keypad_hash:

    getQuestion();
    checkAnswer();

    break;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your score might be going down each time due to the final if/else pair in getQuestion.

Suppose i1==1, the program will execute the first block of code and set correctAnswer.
However, when it gets to the line "if(i1 == 4){" it will spot than i1!=4 and will move to the else, which decrements score.

Does it work if you simply delete the following lines?

```
else{
    score--;
    scoredisplay.setText("" + score);
}
```

EDIT

I have just seen your other question related to this problem and in it you have the lines:

```
case R.id.keypad_hash:
   getQuestion();
   checkAnswer();
```

This also looks odd as getQuestion() will change correctAnswer before you check whether it was correct!  Perhaps it will work better if you switch the order of these lines to:

```
case R.id.keypad_hash:
    checkAnswer();
    getQuestion();
```

Comment: Hey, thanks dude, I swapped them around and the counter is working now! Would you know how I go about limiting the number of questions to ten and then displaying the users score at the end? Presume I need some sort of loop.

Answer (score 0):

That is fine, just make sure editText is not null, and that the text is infact numbers.

Otherwise it will throw nullpointerexception or numberformatexception.

Comment: Do you know why it treats every answer as wrong? I checked correctAnswer by displaying it and they are correct. I've edited the question.

Comment: @Abs90 you mean no eroor is there and only else part id getting executed ?

Comment: @Abs90 We can't tell from your code how you set correctAnswer.  You should output (somehow) the values of mm and correctAnswer, or use a debugger to see those values, if that's possible in Android.

Comment: Make sure that i1 is clamped between 0 and 4, using the % operator. Also, make sure getQuestion is only called once, or else the "correct" answer will change every time. As toto2 said, also try outputting the values of mm as well. (use Log.d())

Comment: int Min = 1; int Max = 4; int i1 = Min + (int)(Math.random() * ((Max - Min) + 1));  that would clap between 0-4 right?

Comment: @JeremyS I've output mm and correctanswer to the screen and they match up. Could the problem be that every time the button is clicked, get question is called? updated it show you

Comment: Yes. you call getquestion every time so the values of checkanswer is different every time. Only call it once when the game starts for the first time.